# C# Padding Decimal Points

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

I want to pad my number decimal points to 6.

So `0.0345` --> become `0.034500`

`0.6` --> become `0.600000`

But no matter what decimal values I put in Math.Round, my code below only pads the decimal points to `5`

```
var amount = Math.Round(0.0345, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
var amount1 = Math.Round(0.0345, 7, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Result:
`amount = 0.03450`

`amount1 = 0.03450`

Thank you.

Comment: In case of `decimal` you can and zero: `amount += 0.000000m`, in case of `double` all you can do is to *format* when representing `amount` as a `string`: `amount.ToString("F6");`

Comment: That kind of padding makes sense to human eyes, computers don't think that 0.034500 and 0.03450 are different values.  Humans don't either, but eyes tend to win.  Decimal inherited a quirk from pre-.NET days, giving them the capability of knowing the number of significant digits.  But without an api to set them, that's why Math.Round() can't do it.  Focus on the eyes, use Decimal.ToString() to keep them happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possibilities; if `amount` is of type `decimal`, you can add *zero*:

```
decimal amount = 0.0345m;

amount += 0.000000m;

Console.Write(amount);
```

Outcome:

```
0.034500
```

Or *represent* `amount` in desired format:

```
decimal amount = 0.0345m; 

Console.Write(amount.ToString("F6"));
```

If `amount` is of type `double` or `float` then `0.034500 == 0.0345` and all you can do is to *format* when representing `amount` as a `string`:

```
double amount = 0.0345;

...

// F6 format string stands for 6 digits after the decimal point
Console.Write(amount.ToString("F6"));
```

**Edit:** In order create such kind of zero you can use

```
public static decimal Zero(int zeroesAfterDecimalPoint) {
  if (zeroesAfterDecimalPoint < 0 || zeroesAfterDecimalPoint > 29)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(zeroesAfterDecimalPoint));

  int[] bits = new int[4];

  bits[3] = zeroesAfterDecimalPoint << 16;

  return new decimal(bits);
}
```

And so have `MyRound` method:

```
private static Decimal MyRound(Decimal value, int digits) {
  return Math.Round(value, digits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) +
         Zero(digits); 
}

private static Decimal MyRound(double value, int digits) => 
  MyRound((decimal)value, digits); 

...

decimal amount = 0.0345m;

Console.WriteLine(MyRound(amount, 6));
Console.WriteLine(MyRound(0.0345, 7)); // let's provide double and 7 digits
```

Outcome:

```
0.034500
0.0345000
```

Comment: not working decimal amount = 0.0345; 
working decimal amount = 0.0345m;

Comment: @childofthealgorithm: sure, since `0.0345` is of type `double` then `decimal amount = 0.0345;` *doesn't compile*; suffix `m` is required: `0.0345m`, sorry for the typo

Comment: You were supposed to get the fix I sent you that way it doesn't make sense

Comment: What is the 'm' at the end of the value? Value is actually a decimal, going to try your first solution.

Comment: @ichachan: suffix `m` means that value is of type `decimal`; value without suffix is of type `double`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you so much this is working great.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use format string with six decimals

```
decimal value = 0.6m;
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.000000}", value);
value = 0.0345m;
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.000000}", value);

// output
// 0.600000
// 0.034500
```

Answer (score 0):

It only works this way if the incoming value is double.

```
            double doubleParsing = 0.0345;

            decimal amount = decimal.Parse(doubleParsing.ToString());

            amount += 0.000000m;

            var result = amount.ToString("F5");
```

Comment: This is really not helpful as answer. Show mess of strigly based code and some strange using of `decimal` - why one would need to convert number to decimal when they can simply `doubleParsing.ToString("F5")` ? Maybe some explanation would help OP/future visitors on why this is actually answers the question.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I know, but the answers above don't work :) Still not getting an answer to my question? What will you do with a value that comes in a Double? Make sure I know OP :)